# Is the textViewResourceId argument always necessary?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

While writing my own adapter that extends the **ArrayAdapter** class, I came across the different constructors available and I noticed they all require a *textViewResourceId* parameter.  So initially, I decided that I would feed my custom adapter class **android.R.id.text1**:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.myRow, android.R.id.text1);
```

However, later on during my development, I decided to override **getView** method where I would

```
TextView label = (TextView) myRow.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
label.setText("Position #" + position);
```

Which worked fine.  But then this question came to mind: if I'm doing the logic for how to display the row, is it really necessary to provide a *textViewResourceId* to the constructor when I initiate my custom adapter? Or is it the case that when you override **getView**, that parameter is no longer necessary? If my thinking is correct, what is the common practice for instantiating the adapter knowing that you will be overriding the display behavior anyways?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are overriding `getView` you do **NOT** need to specify a proper `textViewResourceId`.. You can pass in 0. The only time the `ArrayAdapter` tries to access that ID is within `getView`.. Since you are overriding `getView` and providing your own view `textViewResourceId` is never accessed.. 
Since the super class expects a view ID.. you still need to pass in a view ID into the super call.. however, it can just be 0 since it will never be used

[ArrayAdapter Source confirming all of this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.getView%28int,android.view.View,android.view.ViewGroup%29)

If you do not specify a proper `textViewResourceId` and do not override `getView`.. `getView` in the `ArrayAdapter` assumes your entire view is a `TextView`.. If your view is not a `TextView`.. you will end up with crashes from a ClassCastException..

Comment: (upvote) Rather than pass 0, I would use a constructor that doesn't require `textViewResouceId` at all.

Comment: @Sam - If you wish to use ArrayAdapter you need to pass it the textViewResourceId. There's no avoiding that since it expects it (even if its not valid). You could copy the source code and rewrite the ArrayAdapter so it doesn't require the textViewResourceId. However, for simply avoiding passing a single int its not really worth it.

Comment: @Sam - Or you can create your own Adapter which extends BaseAdapter . You won't get the built in array handling so you'd need to do that yourself. However, you can customize it as much as you want and build in the basic features of handling arrays

Comment: Hmm, I see the confusion. Look closely at [the first two constructors](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.Context%2Cint%29). They use `textViewResourceId` to reference _two different_ parameters... :( I'm saying that you don't need to pass a `R.id.textView`. For instance `new public ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)` is perfectly valid, you don't need to use `new public ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 0)`.

Comment: @Sam - it's a case of them poorly labeling their args. The 1st constructor shouldn't have "textViewResourceId" as the param name.. it should be something like "textViewLayoutId" since its expecting a reference to a layout file. The 1st constructor (the one you linked to) assumes you pass it a layout ID and the layout itself is a textview and nothing else. The other constructors take a layout file and a textview id.. they search the layout file for the textview Id..

Comment: So you can just do MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.myRow); if that's what you're aiming for

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use any kind of build in adapter.

you can extend the [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) and make your own rules of what to show , what type of data to hold etc...

in fact , i almost never used the built in adapters that android has out of the box , because using the baseAdapter is very easy as it is.